# Invalid value encountered in subtract - Softmax, Python

Tags: python, scipy, softmax

I'm using a numerically stabilised version of softmax as:-

```
def softmax(arr):
    print(arr)
    expArr=np.exp(arr-np.max(arr))
    print(expArr)
    return expArr/np.sum(expArr)
```

It is being used as:-

```
def feedforward(x_i,W):
    ...
    outputLayer = softmax(np.dot(network[-1],W[-1]))
    ...
```

And this function is called iteratively:-

```
for j in range(len(x)):
    ....
    network = feedforward(x[j],weights)
    ....
```

Still, for some sequence of arrays, I get the warning:-

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
  expArr=np.exp(arr-np.max(arr))
```

The inputs (and outputs) going to the function right before the warning are:-

```
input
[-1.36678160e+211 -1.97916134e+206 -5.44472726e+204 -5.47948095e+276
 -6.30134248e+251 -4.04707279e+210  7.72371508e+204  1.34861349e+268
  5.47948093e+276  1.06699784e+206]
output
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
input
[-7.06701455e+257  1.47067222e+250              inf             -inf
 -1.13669521e+298 -6.54589076e+254  8.22221348e+250              inf
             -inf -5.44761594e+251]
digit.py:22: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract
  expArr=np.exp(arr-np.max(arr))
output
[ 0.  0. nan  0.  0.  0.  0. nan  0.  0.]
input
[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
output
[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
```

I want to know that even though I stabilised the softmax function by introducing the `np.max(arr)` term, why am I still getting this error, and how can I fix it? Thanks!

Also, I also used the softmax function given in `scipy.special`, but still ended up with the same warning.

Comment: maybe you need to check on the "nan" in the input array. Why it contains "nan"? is this acceptable??

Comment: @mnabil The previous output is used as input, after some modifications. Since previous output has `inf`, its giving me `nan`

Comment: @mnabil I've added more info. I hope its clearer now

Answer (score 1):

"inf" in the input array makes the division to be

```
"<non inf number>/inf"
```

which gives "0" 
and

```
"inf/inf"
```

which gives "nan"

You shall eliminate "inf" from the input array.